# AttributeError for appending a file name?

Tags: python

Pretty simple, really. This code here throws an error:

```
def Send(subject, EEfrom, fromName, to, bodyHtml, bodyText, isTransactional, attachmentFiles = []):
    for name in attachmentFiles:
    attachments.append(('attachments'.name, open(name, 'rb')))
    return ApiClient.Request('POST', '/email/send', {
            'subject': subject,
            'from': EEfrom,
            'fromName': fromName,
            'to': to,
            'bodyHtml': bodyHtml,
            'bodyText': bodyText,
            'isTransactional': isTransactional}, attachments)
```

Upon execution, I'm seeing:

```
 File "sendEmail.py", line 39, in Send
    attachments.append(('attachments'.name, open(name, 'rb')))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I understand what the AttributeError is telling me, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. The fundamental issue on my end about why I don't know how to fix this is because I'm looking at someone else's code that isn't quite working right and I'm trying to understand what they've done in the first place, but I'm unfamiliar with what's going on with the append portion of this and what the .name is supposed to do, along with why they're opening this binary file for reading. Ultimately it's supposed to attach a file to an email.

Comment: 1 - The code in the for loop is not properly indented.   2 - 'whatever'.name Will always give an error because 'whatever' is a string and strings font have a .name attribute. Given I am not sure what the code is trying to do I have no further way of helping you

Comment: I clearly stated that I didn’t know what I was doing. I did look at the documentation for lists and appends. Don’t be rude.

Answer (score 0):

'attachments' is string. attachments is variable.
Remove the quotes and try.

Comment: Removing the quotes just throws another similar error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'"

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because strings do not have the `name` attribute. In this case, the string `'attachments'` is being treated like a different object:

```
'attachments'.name ...
```

This can be fixed by using the proper object to get the attribute `name` from. In this case, it appears like you want to access `attachments.name` so the line should read:

```
attachments.append((attachments.name, open(name, 'rb')))
```

Additionally, the `for` loop is not properly indented, although this may simply be a discrepancy from posting on Stack Overflow. The loop should read:

```
for name in attachmentFiles:
    attachments.append(...)
```

Comment: Thanks kindly! But, another error when removing quotes: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'"